# Increase score based on maximum matching words in Marklogic

Tags: marklogic

I would like  to search for documents which will have maximum matching words from string. More number of matching words documents should score higher.
Example I have string "Today is my birthday" I have documents like below

```
{
  "Id": "Doc1",
  "TitleName": "my birthday"
}
{
  "Id": "Doc2",
  "TitleName": "birthday"
}
{
  "Id": "Doc3",
  "TitleName": "Today is my teacher's birthday"
}
{
  "Id": "Doc4",
  "TitleName": "Holiday"
}
```

In this case Doc3 should get highest score then Doc1,Doc2

Answer (score 2):

That is what you get out of the box with the default scoring and relevancy based result sorting. If you supply a sequence of [`cts:word-query()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:word-query) within a [`cts:or-query()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:or-query), the `logtfidf` relevance calculation is applied and would return the documents in the order that you want.

## [log(tf)*idf Calculation](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/relevance#id_91509)

> The `logtfidf` method of relevance calculation is the default relevance calculation, and it is the option score-logtfidf of `cts:search`. The logtfidf method takes into account term frequency (how often a term occurs in a single fragment) and document frequency (in how many documents does the term occur) when calculating the score. Most search engines use a relevance formula that is derived by some computation that takes into account term frequency and document frequency.

> The `logtfidf` method (the default scoring method) uses the following formula to calculate relevance:

```
log(term frequency) * (inverse document frequency)
```

So, with this search:

```
let $phrase := "Today is my birthday"
let $word-queries := tokenize($phrase, " ") ! cts:word-query(.)
return
  cts:search(doc(), cts:or-query($word-queries ))
```

It returns the documents in the order: Doc3, Doc1, Doc2

Comment: Thanks. Working as expected!!